# Проверить есть ли уже добавляемое слово в БД

Tags: java, android

На activity есть два поля и кнопка. В первое поле вводим слово, во второе перевод и по нажатию на кнопку запись добавляется в БД. Все работает хорошо. Но решил реализовать проверку, а нет ли добавляемого слова уже в БД и если оно есть выводить сообщение что уже есть слово. В свой код добавил запрос и в курсор выбираю данные удовлетворяющие этому запросу. При попытке добавить слово программа вылетает. Помогите найти ошибку.

Вот код вспомогательного класса где используетс уже готовая БД, где есть методы открытия БД и тд. там все хорошо выкладываю чтобы знать что там за методы

```
public class DictionaryDBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = DictionaryDBHeler.class.getSimpleName();

    //Пусть к БД
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/test.prog1/databases/";
    //Имя файла базы данных
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbase.db";
    //Версия базы данных. При изменении схемы увеличить на единицу
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";
    public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_WORD = "word";
    public static final String COLUMN_TRANSLATION = "translation";

    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    //Конструктор
    //Третий параметр null в суперклассе используется для работы с курсорами. Сейчас их не используем, поэтому оставим в покое.
    public DictionaryDBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //ничего не делать - база уже есть
        }else{
            //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Проверяет, существует ли уже эта база, чтобы не копировать каждый раз при запуске приложения
     * @return true если существует, false если не существует
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch(SQLiteException e){
            //база еще не существует
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Копирует базу из папки assets заместо созданной локальной БД
     * Выполняется путем копирования потока байтов.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Открываем локальную БД как входящий поток
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        //Путь ко вновь созданной БД
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        //Открываем пустую базу данных как исходящий поток
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //перемещаем байты из входящего файла в исходящий
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //закрываем потоки
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //открываем БД
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }


}
```

А вот класс активити где пытаюсь реализовать требуемое

```
import test.prog1.data.DictionaryDBHeler;

public class ActivityAdd extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText txtWord;
    private EditText txtTranslation;
    private TextView txtResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        txtWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
        txtTranslation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTranslation);
        txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
    }

    private void addWord() {
        //Считывает данные с текстовых полей
        String word = txtWord.getText().toString().trim();
        String translation = txtTranslation.getText().toString().trim();
        DictionaryDBHeler dictionaryDBHeler = new DictionaryDBHeler(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dictionaryDBHeler.getWritableDatabase();
        if (!word.isEmpty()) {
            if (!translation.isEmpty()) {

                String query = "SELECT " + dictionaryDBHeler.COLUMN_WORD + " FROM " + dictionaryDBHeler.TABLE_NAME
                        + " WHERE " + dictionaryDBHeler.COLUMN_WORD + " = " + "\"" + word + "\"";

                Cursor cursor = dictionaryDBHeler.database.rawQuery(query, null);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(dictionaryDBHeler.COLUMN_WORD, word);
                values.put(dictionaryDBHeler.COLUMN_TRANSLATION, translation);

                // Вставляем новый ряд в базу данных и запоминаем его идентификатор
                long newRowId = db.insert(dictionaryDBHeler.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

                // Выводим сообщение в успешном случае или при ошибке
                if (newRowId == -1) { // Если ID  -1, значит произошла ошибка
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка при добавлении нового слова", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Слово " + "\"" + word + "\"" + " добавлено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Введите перевод", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите слово", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onClickAddButton(View view) {
        addWord();
    }
}
```

Когда добавляю для начала строку Cursor cursor = dictionaryDBHeler.database.rawQuery(query, null); чтобы проверить вообще что-то появляется в курсоре, то вылетает ошибка. Без этой строки все работает.

---

Запустил приложение в виртуальном устройстве. В консоли выдало следующее

```html
11/20 17:50:11: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Android\projects\test\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/test.prog1
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/test.prog1"
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "test.prog1/test.prog1.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 2437 on device emulator-5554
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/test.prog1-1/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 32456 of [bda77dda96]
E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:32456: (2) open(/data/data/test.prog1/databases/dbase.db) - 
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/test.prog1/databases/dbase.db'.
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
                      at test.prog1.data.DictionaryDBHeler.checkDataBase(DictionaryDBHeler.java:69)
                      at test.prog1.data.DictionaryDBHeler.createDataBase(DictionaryDBHeler.java:45)
                      at test.prog1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed

                  [ 11-20 14:52:30.254  2437: 2437 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa0b5f280, tid 2437
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x951fc900 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0xafbbe8d0
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: test.prog1, PID: 2437
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                      at test.prog1.ActivityAdd.addWord(ActivityAdd.java:51)
                      at test.prog1.ActivityAdd.onClickAddButton(ActivityAdd.java:77)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Покажите содержимое стек-трейса при падении приложения.

Comment: Как увидеть содержимое стек-трейса?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо дополнительного запроса к БД и обработки ответа настроить unique constraint на поле, для которого требуется уникальность. В случае попытки вставки (или изменения) значения которое уже присутствует в таблице - бд вернёт соответствующую ошибку, а вам останется только её обработать.